# Как в VS 2010 Конструктор поставить над Исходным кодом?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, в конструкторе html-форм нет такой возможности в отличии от xaml например.

Comment: мда... странно этой возможности нету...